# jQuery .getJSON() and LINQtoSQL Using Statement

Tags: jquery, linq-to-sql, using-statement

Can somebody explain to me why this code returns a 500 Internal server error when I call it using `$.getJSON()`:

```
    public JsonResult SomeItemList()
    {
        SomeDBDataContext _dbContext;
        IEnumerable<SomeModel> _items;
        using (_dbContext = new SomeDBDataContext())
        {
            _items= from list in _dbContext.GetItems()
                           select new SomeModel
                           {
                               Name= list.Name,
                               ID = list.ID
                           };
            return Json(_items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
```

While this one works with no errors at all:

```
public JsonResult SomeItemList()
        {
            SomeDBDataContext _dbContextv = new SomeDBDataContext();
            IEnumerable<SomeModel> _items;
            _items= from list in _dbContext.GetItems()
                               select new SomeModel
                               {
                                   Name= list.Name,
                                   ID = list.ID
                               };
                return Json(_items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The only difference is that I put the first one inside the Using statement to be disposed after it's done with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might because the serialization starts after you exit the using thus closing the connection to the database. If need to send the query by doing .ToList() to the database before returning the json it should work.

```
public JsonResult SomeItemList()
{
    SomeDBDataContext _dbContext;
    IEnumerable<SomeModel> _items;
    using (_dbContext = new SomeDBDataContext())
    {
        _items = (from list in _dbContext.GetItems()
                       select new SomeModel
                       {
                           Name= list.Name,
                           ID = list.ID
                       }).ToList();
        return Json(_items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
}
```